# Page size causing error in gridview DataBind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, pagertemplate

I am facing a strange issue or maybe i am doing a silly mistake.
I have a datatable which contains five rows.
I am creating a gridview from codebehind.
for pagination if i specify `Page size =5` (the size of datatable) everything is fine but when i specify the page size less than the size of the datatable e.g. `Page size=2`,
I am getting :

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

in `gvEmployee.DataBind();`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace demogrid
{
    public partial class grid : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
                table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
                table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
                table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

                // Here we add five DataRows.
                table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
                table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
                table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
                table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
                table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);
                BindData(table);
            }
        }
        protected void BindData(DataTable dt)
        {
            GridView gvEmployee = new GridView();
            gvEmployee.AllowPaging = true;
            gvEmployee.PageSize = 5;//getting error if the page size is less than 5
            gvEmployee.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

            if (dt != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    BoundField boundfield = new BoundField();
                    boundfield.DataField = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
                    boundfield.HeaderText = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
                    gvEmployee.Columns.Add(boundfield);
                }
                gvEmployee.DataSource = dt;
                gvEmployee.DataBind();
                gvEmployee.Width = 600;
                gvEmployee.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "header";
                gvEmployee.RowStyle.CssClass = "rowstyle";

                Panel1.Controls.Add(gvEmployee);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**StackTrace:**

```
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.get_StateFormatter()
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.BuildCallbackArgument(Int32 pageIndex)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateNumericPager(TableRow row, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource, Boolean addFirstLastPageButtons)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.InitializePager(GridViewRow row, Int32 columnSpan, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState rowState, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[] fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data)
       at System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect()
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind()
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind()
       at demogrid.grid.BindData(DataTable dt) in c:\Users\sample\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\demogrid\demogrid\grid.aspx.cs:line 59
       at demogrid.grid.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\sample\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\demogrid\demogrid\grid.aspx.cs:line 32
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that's the line throwing the exception?  Or perhaps it's coming from code within the data binding itself, such as in-line binding templates on the page or an event handler for data bound events?

Comment: hi david thanks for the response,yes i am sure.I checked with both the scenario and i am getting error only when i am binding the grid with pagesize less than the size of the datatable.

Comment: Well, if that's the line throwing the exception, then somehow `gvEmployee` is `null`.  If that's not the case then that's not the line throwing the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused because no Pager Template is set to your GridView.
I have modified your code to get you started. First add RowDataBound handler and set your Pager:

```
    protected void BindData(DataTable dt)
    {
        GridView gvEmployee = new GridView();
        gvEmployee.AllowPaging = true;
        gvEmployee.PageSize = 4;//this Will work now
        gvEmployee.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        if (dt != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                BoundField boundfield = new BoundField();
                boundfield.DataField = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
                boundfield.HeaderText = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
                gvEmployee.Columns.Add(boundfield);
            }
            gvEmployee.DataSource = dt;
            gvEmployee.RowDataBound += gvEmployee_RowDataBound;
            gvEmployee.PagerTemplate = new MyTemplate();
            gvEmployee.DataBind();
            gvEmployee.Width = 600;
            gvEmployee.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "header";
            gvEmployee.RowStyle.CssClass = "rowstyle";

            Panel1.Controls.Add(gvEmployee);
        }
    }

    void gvEmployee_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Row.RowType)
        {
            case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
                break;
            case DataControlRowType.EmptyDataRow:
                break;
            case DataControlRowType.Footer:
                break;
            case DataControlRowType.Header:
                break;
            case DataControlRowType.Pager:
                //TODO: handle your pager...
                break;
            case DataControlRowType.Separator:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

And here is basic Pager control:

```
public class MyTemplate : WebControl, ITemplate
{
    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        //TODO: create your pager controls...
    }
}
```

This will do the job.

Comment: Here is sample from Microsoft (using the same principle), you can also download source code:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972960.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The Exception is occurring because your **GridView** is not a control on PAGE yet and your are calling **DataBind**.
**You must add the control on the page before you databind**. 
And Also you must implement **PageIndexChanging** Event to handle Page Changing Event. 
One more thing is that you need to move your datatable code from  **if (!IsPostBack)** block, because it wont be executed when Page POSTBACK and control wont be on page anymore when page is changed or any POSTBACK event is fired.
Here is a working code for you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace demogrid
{
    public partial class grid : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    GridView gvEmployee = new GridView();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

        }
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

        // Here we add five DataRows.
        table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);
        BindData(table);
    }
    protected void BindData(DataTable dt)
    {
        gvEmployee.AllowPaging = true;
        gvEmployee.PageSize = 2;
        gvEmployee.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        gvEmployee.PageIndexChanging += gvEmployee_PageIndexChanging;
        if (dt != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                BoundField boundfield = new BoundField();
                boundfield.DataField = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
                boundfield.HeaderText = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
                gvEmployee.Columns.Add(boundfield);
            }
            Panel1.Controls.Add(gvEmployee);
            gvEmployee.DataSource = dt;
            gvEmployee.DataBind();
            gvEmployee.Width = 600;
            gvEmployee.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "header";
            gvEmployee.RowStyle.CssClass = "rowstyle";

        }
    }

    void gvEmployee_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        gvEmployee.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        gvEmployee.DataBind();

    }


}
}
```

Comment: Please share what problem or error you faced in this?

Comment: i got the same error i got earlier,i have shared the stacktrace

Comment: Can you please share your code after you integrated my code?

Comment: UI .aspx PAGE = http://www.textsnip.com/buq3so
CodeBehind = http://www.textsnip.com/xju8yr

Comment: you solved my issue, even if its a couple years later. I was moving some code around with my page lifecycle and was basically adding the control then later in the lifecycle removing it *derp*. I wish this could be a caught exception with some common causes in the description.